# Sqoop using '--direct' option fails with mysqldump exit code 2 and 3

Tags: hadoop, mysql, sqoop, emr

I am running Sqoop in AWS EMR. I am trying to copy a table ~10 GB from MySQL into HDFS.

I get the following exception

```
15/07/06 12:19:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1435664372091_0048_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: mysqldump terminated with status 3
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:485)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:49)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:152)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:773)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

15/07/06 12:19:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1435664372091_0048_m_000005_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.io.IOException: mysqldump terminated with status 2
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:485)
at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.MySQLDumpMapper.map(MySQLDumpMapper.java:49)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:152)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:773)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:175)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1548)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:170)

15/07/06 12:19:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/07/06 12:19:20 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 25% reduce 0%
15/07/06 12:19:22 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 38% reduce 0%
15/07/06 12:19:23 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 50% reduce 0%
15/07/06 12:19:24 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 75% reduce 0%
15/07/06 12:19:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%

15/07/06 12:23:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1435664372091_0048 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1435664372091_0048_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

15/07/06 12:23:11 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8
        Job Counters 
        Failed map tasks=28
        Launched map tasks=28
        Other local map tasks=28
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=34760760
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=5793460
        Total vcore-seconds taken by all map tasks=5793460
        Total megabyte-seconds taken by all map tasks=8342582400
15/07/06 12:23:11 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead
15/07/06 12:23:11 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 829.8697 seconds (0 bytes/sec)
15/07/06 12:23:11 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead
15/07/06 12:23:11 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.
15/07/06 12:23:11 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!
```

If I run with out '--direct' option, I get the communication exception as in https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/SQOOP-186

I have set 'net-write-timeout' and 'net-read-timeout' values in MySQL to 6000.

My Sqoop command looks like this

```
sqoop import -D mapred.task.timeout=0 --fields-terminated-by '\t' --escaped-by '\\' --optionally-enclosed-by '\"' --bindir ./ --connect jdbc:mysql://<remote ip>/<mysql db> --username tuser --password tuser --table table1 --target-dir=/base/table1 --split-by id -m 8 --direct
```

How to fix the same ? Am I missing something.

I have also created SQOOP JIRA - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2411

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error occur when Sqoop cannot divide the key space evenly and one of the map tasks processes zero rows of data. Possible workarounds are changing the number of mappers (`-n`) or specifying a different key column (`--split-by`) that has evenly distributed values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running the below command and see whether it works. Not sure but I guess there is some problem with your sqoop import command.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:mysql://<remote ip>/<mysql db>" --password "core" --username "core" --table "TABLENAME" --target-dir "/sqoopfile2" -m 8 --direct
```

Comment: Nope. It still doesn't work. Fails with the same error.

Comment: Have you imported the small table using the --direct option?.  --direct option will by pass the JDBC interface and uses the mysql utilities. Also verify whether the mysqldump and mysqlimport are installed on your both the data nodes and added them to PATH.